# Does one’s SEM latent variable scaling convention (unit variance vs. marker variable) impact the interpretation of unstandardized indirect effects?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable

This is my first time running a structural equation model, and my question involves understanding if my approach to setting the scale of the latent factor has any implications on if or how I should interpret the unstandardized indirect effects. Specifically, I used the unit variance approach (also referred to as "fixed factor method" or "reference factor method"), which fixes the latent factor's variance to 1 and its mean to 0, thus allowing all factor loadings to be freely estimated, rather than the marker variable approach which sets the scale of the latent factor by forcing one indicator to have an intercept of 0 and a factor loading to 1.

My question is, does the unit variance scaling convention that I used have any implications on if I can report/interpret the *un*standardized indirect effects? From my understanding, the unit variance scaling convention already standardized the latent variables; and therefore, I am unsure of what exactly makes the standardized indirect effects in this case different from the unstandardized indirect effects. Or even if the unstandardized indirect effect is able to be interpreted.

Comment: In your standardized latent variables case in SEM do you mean how you should interpret the unstandardized indirect effects of one latent variable on a manifest variable? If so you have to unstandardize your latent variables to be able to report such unstandardized indirect effects. Note sometimes you may not have any available sample of latent variable or impossible to obtain, then you may have trouble to unstandardize them via metrics such as mean and variance..

Comment: Thanks for offering some thoughts! All of my variables are latent variables. I am using Lavaan and included "std.lv=true", which standardized the latent dependent variables by fixing the intercepts to 0 and the residual variances to 1, and for the exogenous variables, fixed the mean to be 0 and the variance to be 1. I guess I am still trying to figure out if the scaling convention I used automatically eliminates my ability to report the unstandardized indirect effects, or if my only option is to report just the standardized indirect effects. Do you have any thoughts about that? Thanks again!

Comment: If you are interested in the magnitude of the indirect effects in the units of measure of the original variables, then you should use an identity matrix as the scaling matrix and report the unstandardized indirect effects. If you are more interested in the relative strength of the indirect effects, then you may want to use a non-identity scaling matrix and report the standardized indirect effects. It all depends on your scaling matrix for your original model, once in standardized form, you cannot report unstandardized effects therein. Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Hi Mohottnad! This phrase caught my attention, "once in standardized form, you cannot report unstandardized effects therein" During the model identification phase, I chose to use the unit variance scaling approach rather than marker variable approach (this allowed me to observe all the item factor loadings). Would you consider this decision to lock me into "standardized", such that they cannot be unstandardized? E.g.: b=.45, CI(.34, .57), B=.38, p<.001. Here b is my unstandardized indirect effect-do you think this would be okay to report? Thanks so much and happy holidays!

Comment: If your indirect effect has a unstandardized estimate of b = .45, its relation with the standardized estimate B is: b = B * sd(predictor) * sd(outcome) / r(predictor, outcome), where sd(predictor) and sd(outcome) are the standard deviations of the predictor and outcome variables, respectively, and r(predictor, outcome) is the correlation between the predictor and outcome variables. It is generally a good idea to report both standardized and unstandardized estimates in your analysis.

Comment: It's also important to note that when you convert standardized estimates back to the original scale, the confidence intervals and p-values may not be accurate, as they are based on the assumption that the data are standardized. If you want to report results in the original units and also report accurate confidence intervals and p-values, you will need to re-estimate the model using the original data rather than the standardized data.

Comment: Thanks Mohottnad!! This has been super helpful.